# Get batch predictions from a custom trained model : JSON structure Isues

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to reproduce the Batch predictions given in this example:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-p2p-predictions#5

First I use this JSON lines file structure:

```json
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It works well.

When I try this one in the second example

```json
{ "values": [1, 2, 3, 4], "key": 1 }
{ "values": [5, 6, 7, 8], "key": 2 }
```

the batch failed:

> Due to one or more errors, this batch prediction job was canceled on Dec 18, 2023 at 12:23PM

In the log I have this error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

It's not clear to me.

This is how I get my two different file jsonl

```py
with open('input_file20.jsonl', 'w') as fichier:
    # Convertir chaque élément de la liste en chaîne de caractères et les écrire dans le fichier
    for element in x_test_list:
        fichier.write(str(element) + '\n')
        
        
input_json_list = [{"values": element, "key": entry} for element, entry in zip(x_test_list, image_path_list)]

with open('input_file21.jsonl', 'w') as fichier:
    # Convertir chaque élément de la liste en chaîne de caractères et les écrire dans le fichier
    for element in input_json_list:
        fichier.write(str(element) + '\n')
```

And this is how they looks like:

```
[[[5.0, 20.0, 17.0], ... [12.0, 28.0, 18.0], [13.0, 29.0, 18.0]]]
```

And

```
{'values': [[[5.0, 20.0, 17.0], [5.0, 20.0, 17.0], ... [13.0, 29.0, 18.0]]], 'key': 'gs://prototype-to-production-bucket-sb/x_test_image/test-image_1922.jpeg'}
```

I don't find what is missing with the second example.

Comment: this may help :https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-batch-predictions

Comment: If your file contains `'values'` and `'key'`, then it is not JSON, it should have `"values"` and `"key"`. It sounds like you're relying on standard Python string production instead of generating actual JSON.

Comment: Hi Mark , thanks for your answer . I've corrected the JSON file. with `"values" and "key"` but I've still have some error : `('Post request fails. Cannot get predictions. Error: Exceeded retries: Non-OK result 400 ({\n    "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: values of \'instances\' list. Error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: JSON object: does not have named input: values"\n}) from server, retry=3, ellapsed=0.11s.', 2)`